# Powershell: i am trying to SetSelected item in Listbox

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-2022

i am trying to `SetSelected` in my `Listbox` so once i have filtered it will automatically select the filtered result. please see below code i am using to try to make it work

```
$textBox2_TextChanged = {
$texttomatch = $textBox2.text
$filter = GCI $textbox3.text 
$listbox1.Items.clear()
    foreach ($filt in $Filter)
        {
        if ($filt -Like "*$($textbox2.Text)*" )
            {            
            $listbox1.Items.add($filt)
             $listbox1.SetSelected($filt, $true)   
            }           
        }   
    else
    {
    $GetFile = GCI $textbox3.Text -Filter *.pdf -File
    ForEach($File in $GetFile){
    $listBox1.Items.Add($File)
    }
}
}
```

the result on the `Listbox` but i cant seem to get the `SetSelected` working.

please see below images

Result i am getting

[image: Result i am getting]

Result that i want

[image]

Answer (score 0):

after quite a bit of googling it turns out all i had to do was the below

```
$listbox1.Items.add($filt)
$listbox1.SetSelected(0, $true)
```